# From Solve to Fsolve

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, solver, equation-solving

I have three equations in three unknowns that I would like to solve. 
I am specifying the equations with `symbolic toolbox`. I know I can use `solve` function to ask matlab to find me a numeric solution. However, with 3 equations in 3 unknowns, matlab should be able to find an analytical solution (`fsolve`). I am just not sure how to change the code so that I can use `fsolve` instead of `solve`.

Below my code:

clear all

```
syms Kl Kh alpha nu w phi delta P beta zh zl Ezh Ezl 

nu1 = (1/(1-nu));

f1 = ((zl * (Kl^alpha))^nu1  + (zh * (Kh^alpha))^nu1) * nu^(nu*nu1) * (w^(-nu*nu1)) - w/phi + delta*(Kl + Kh)*P
f2 = Kh - (( (1-beta*(1-delta))*P * (w^(nu1*nu))*(nu^(nu*nu1)) ) / (beta*alpha* (Ezh)^nu1) )^((1-nu)/(alpha+nu-1))
f3 = Kl - (( (1-beta*(1-delta))*P * (w^(nu1*nu))*(nu^(nu*nu1)) ) / (beta*alpha* (Ezl)^nu1) )^((1-nu)/(alpha+nu-1))

f1 = subs(f1, {alpha, beta, nu, phi,delta, zh, zl, Ezh, Ezl, P}, {0.27, 0.96, 0.60, 2.15,0.065,1.11687642219068,0.895354204038589,1.07811003137331,0.934120594855956, 0.95})
f2 = subs(f2, {alpha, beta, nu, phi,delta, zh, zl, Ezh, Ezl, P}, {0.27, 0.96, 0.60, 2.15,0.065,1.11687642219068,0.895354204038589,1.07811003137331,0.934120594855956, 0.95})
f3 = subs(f3, {alpha, beta, nu, phi,delta, zh, zl, Ezh, Ezl, P}, {0.27, 0.96, 0.60, 2.15,0.065,1.11687642219068,0.895354204038589,1.07811003137331,0.934120594855956, 0.95})



S = solve([f1 == 0, f2 == 0, f3 == 0],...
    [w, Kh, Kl], 'ReturnConditions', true);
```

Comment: `fsolve` is used to find a *numerical* solution, not analytical ones. `solve`, in the symbolic math toolbox, can find analytical solutions (if they exist) in some cases, but other wise will use variable precision math to find a numeric one. Are you looking for a numeric solution?

Comment: Yes, my apologies. I meant a numerical solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I found the solution.

Here's the code for completion:

```
function SSfunction = SSfunction(x)


syms alphaa nu phi delta p betaa zh zl ezh ezl 

nu1 = (1/(1-nu));

f1 = ((zl * (x(3)^alphaa))^nu1  + (zh * (x(2)^alphaa))^nu1) * nu^(nu*nu1) * (x(1)^(-nu*nu1)) - x(1)/phi - delta*(x(3) + x(2))*p;
f2 = x(2) - (( betaa*alphaa*(ezh^(nu1)) * (nu^(nu*nu1)) )/( (1-betaa*(1-delta))*p* (x(1)^(nu*nu1)) ))^((1-nu)/(1-alphaa-nu));
f3 = x(3) - (( betaa*alphaa*(ezl^(nu1)) * (nu^(nu*nu1)) )/( (1-betaa*(1-delta))*p* (x(1)^(nu*nu1)) ))^((1-nu)/(1-alphaa-nu));

f1 = subs(f1, {alphaa, betaa, nu, phi,delta, zh, zl, ezh, ezl, p}, {0.27, 0.96, 0.60, 2.15,0.065,1.11687642219068,0.895354204038589,1.07811003137331,0.934120594855956, 0.950});
f3 = subs(f1, {alphaa, betaa, nu, phi,delta, zh, zl, ezh, ezl, p}, {0.27, 0.96, 0.60, 2.15,0.065,1.11687642219068,0.895354204038589,1.07811003137331,0.934120594855956, 0.950});
f2 = subs(f1, {alphaa, betaa, nu, phi,delta, zh, zl, ezh, ezl, p}, {0.27, 0.96, 0.60, 2.15,0.065,1.11687642219068,0.895354204038589,1.07811003137331,0.934120594855956, 0.950});



SSfunction(1) = eval(f1)
SSfunction(2) = eval(f2)
SSfunction(3) = eval(f3)


end

x0 = [1,2,0.7];
fun = @SSfunction;
x = fsolve(fun,x0)
```

Comment: Two comments. First, it generally a bad practice to name the output of a function the same as the function itself (`SSfunction`). Also, this solution is inefficient because the symbolic expressions are converted to floating point each time the `fsolve` optimization called the objective function. In very special cases, this method might be useful if you have a loss of significance or other numerical issue in the equations. That doesn't appear to be the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`matlabFunction`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) to convert your symbolic expressions to a vectorized numeric function that can be directly used by `fsolve`:

```
...
f = matlabFunction([f1;f2;f3],'Vars',{[w;Kh;Kl]});

w0 = 1;
Kh0 = 1;
Kl0 = 1;
x0 = [w0;Kh0;Kl0];
x = fsolve(f,x0)
```

This will be an order of magnitude faster than using the the symbolic expressions themselves in `fsolve`. For more speed, you could also just get rid of symbolic math entirely by vectorizing your function manually:

```
alpha = 0.27;
beta = 0.96;
nu = 0.6;
phi = 2.15;
delta = 0.065;
zh = 1.11687642219068;
zl = 0.895354204038589;
Ezh = 1.07811003137331;
Ezl = 0.934120594855956;
P = 0.95;
nu1 = (1/(1-nu));

f = @(w,Kh,Kl)[((zl * (Kl.^alpha))^nu1  + (zh * (Kh.^alpha))^nu1) * nu^(nu*nu1) .* (w.^(-nu*nu1)) - w/phi + delta*(Kl + Kh)*P;
               Kh - (( (1-beta*(1-delta))*P * (w.^(nu1*nu))*(nu^(nu*nu1)) ) / (beta*alpha* (Ezh)^nu1) )^((1-nu)/(alpha+nu-1));
               Kl - (( (1-beta*(1-delta))*P * (w.^(nu1*nu))*(nu^(nu*nu1)) ) / (beta*alpha* (Ezl)^nu1) )^((1-nu)/(alpha+nu-1))];

w0 = 1;
Kh0 = 1;
Kl0 = 1;
x0 = [w0;Kh0;Kl0];
x = fsolve(@(x)f(x(1,:),x(2,:),x(3,:)),x0)
```